# How to use MapView in android using google map V2?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to show a map in on of my activity.

In google map V1 we use -

```
 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:apiKey="@string/api_map_key"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true" />
```

and extend the activity by using MapActivity class.

In Versing 2 it uses Fragment instead of mapview and have to extend activity by FragmentActivity  instead normal Activity.
ex-

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Now Can I use Same way to create mapview instead of Fragment using version 2 .()

Can anyone use MapView using V2?

Comment: check the doc https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start. No you should use fragment

Comment: @Raghunandan There is [MapView in V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView) too. You don't need to use fragment. Note that `MapView` (and API as a whole) from v1 and v2 are not compatible.

Comment: @MaciejGórski i saw the docs can you post a link for an example of google map api v2 using mapview.

Answer (score 158):

yes you can use MapView in v2...
for further details you can get help from this

https://gist.github.com/joshdholtz/4522551

---

## **`SomeFragment.java`**

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{
 
    MapView mapView;
    GoogleMap map;
 
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, container, false);
 
        // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
        mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 
    
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
        
 
        return v;
    }
 
   @Override
   public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
       map = googleMap;
       map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
       map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
       /*
       //in old Api Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory call
        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
       */
        
        // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
        /*CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(43.1, -87.9), 10);
        map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);*/
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(43.1, -87.9)));

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mapView.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }
 
}
```

---

## **`AndroidManifest.xml`**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="your_key"/>
        
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    
    </application>
 
</manifest>
```

---

## **`some_layout.xml`**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    
    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i Got this type of error Declare this in manifest file    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

Comment: add mapView.onResume() to display the map immediately

Comment: that was method in old api, new it is change to getMapAsync()
Updated code without run, check it.

Comment: do we need some gradle settings?

Comment: @VasilValchev yes, add play services dependency

Comment: mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState); will always re create the map if it is pop from backstack!

Answer (score 17):

More complete sample from [here](https://gist.github.com/joshdholtz/4522551) and [here](http://ucla.jamesyxu.com/?p=287).

Or you can check out my layout sample. p.s no need to put API key in the map view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/nearby_lv"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@color/white"
              android:layout_weight="1"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: These all tutorials are helpful but they are for either `eclipse` or older version of `android studio`

Comment: Yes, things change especially tools.

Comment: @Moeez Which "tutorials"? The linked examples ar far away from tutorials. And they don't say anything about the IDE.

Answer (score 7):

I created dummy sample for Google Maps v2 Android with Kotlin and AndroidX

You can find complete project here: [github-link](https://github.com/murgupluoglu/googlemap-dummy-sample-android)

## **`MainActivity.kt`**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

val position = LatLng(-33.920455, 18.466941)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    with(mapView) {
        // Initialise the MapView
        onCreate(null)
        // Set the map ready callback to receive the GoogleMap object
        getMapAsync{
            MapsInitializer.initialize(applicationContext)
            setMapLocation(it)
        }
    }
}

private fun setMapLocation(map : GoogleMap) {
    with(map) {
        moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 13f))
        addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(position))
        mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL
        setOnMapClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Clicked on map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    mapView.onResume()
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    mapView.onPause()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    mapView.onDestroy()
}

override fun onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory()
    mapView.onLowMemory()
 }
}
```

## **`AndroidManifest.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.murgupluoglu.googlemap">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="API_KEY_HERE" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

## **`activity_main.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please help me out with a situation where first i need to check location permission and then load the mapView? 
Thanks in advance!