# How to create Google Map Android appication for blind people?

Tags: android, google-maps

How do I create Android Google Map application for blind people?

I want to use map view (Google Map) in my application and navigator. Here the navigator tells them where they walk. It means on road there if left or right turn is there, so navigator can tell us there is left or right turn. Does anyone have any link or tutorial source code?

Comment: read this https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView and this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19806967/1675954

Comment: Your idea is very good.... this type of app should be there.... go ahead with your idea....

Comment: Ya sure will do that Kushal