# Mapview gives nullpointerexception fragment

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fragment, android-mapview, oncreate

I'm getting a nullpointerexception when I try to do:

```
mapview.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Here's my code:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.onResume();
    .........
```

LOGCAT:

```
01-14 11:36:40.744 27070-27070/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.maptest/com.test.maptest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5403)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.ad.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.h.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.y.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.bd.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.ev.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.af.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.w.onTransact(SourceFile:66)
                                                   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:310)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapViewDelegate$zza$zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$3.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.zzzW(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.test.maptest.TestFragment.onCreateView(TestFragment.java:343)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2042)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:165)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:543)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1170)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5132)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5403) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.16'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
```

}

The thing is I'm only getting this in one phone with 4.2.2, all the other phones with different versions are working. The map is displayed and everything works fine.
Can anyone help me figure it out what's going on?
Thanks.

Edit: This particular phone used to work with this code a few months ago, so maybe the problem is newer google play services and support libraries?
If so, how can we correct it?

Comment: @Ms Yvette Added logcat and dependecies

Answer (score 0):

Because you have called

```
mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mapView.onResume();
```

These methods dont need to be called by you. They will be executed by Android itself. Follow mapview tutorial correctly. :)

Also dont do stuff onCreateView, do stuff onViewCreated Method of fragment. Please post the xml file you are initializing.

[How to use MapView in android using google map V2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16536414/how-to-use-mapview-in-android-using-google-map-v2)

https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos%2Fapp%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fexample%2Fmapdemo%2FBasicMapDemoActivity.java

Comment: Where's the correct tutorial? Why does it work on several other phones?

Comment: Nevertheless the usage is wrong, it had to break sometime. Maybe it breaks if its reinitialized.

Comment: The provided link is what I'm doing. Where's the usage wrong? Using Google Play Services 8.4.0 as shown on dependencies

Comment: Also the mapview.onResume() is there only to show the map right away. If I remove it it still gives nullpointerexception.....

Comment: Given links also call mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mapView.onResume(); methods