# Creating a google map in tab with gps location marked in android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, gps

I am a newbie to android development. I want to develop an app which have three tabs.

1. First tab will be `My Location` in which there is a map and a pin which is marking my location
2. On second tab there will be a camera option, through which i can take pictures and those pictures will be saved in the memory located by OS to the app.
3. The saved pictures will be shown in a slider

As for `2` and `3`, i'll have some idea but for `1` i couldn't find any help. I did find some tutorials but all of them are for `eclipse` but i am using `android studio`.

During a study i found that `Fragment` is a way to do it so i started to follow this [tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-in-google-maps-using-api-v2-with-supportmapfragment/), but as i said earlier i am newbie and all tutorials are for eclipse.

**Update 1**

I have created 3 classes and 3 layout files each for each tab, bellow is the class for `MyLocation` tab

```
public class MyLocation extends Fragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_location, container, false);


    return rootView;
 }   }
```

I am stuck to it now and don't know what to do

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Whats your problem actually, where you stuck? have you create tab and fragments?

Comment: Yes, i have created tabs using `tab activity` and also created fragments

Comment: than whats your problem, inside fragment you can use map

Comment: I can't find a way to load map, previously i made an app which shows me coordinates on a button click

Comment: @MohitSuthar kindly see the update in my question

Comment: check it out this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19806967/4951663

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133991/discussion-between-faisal1208-and-mohit-suthar).

Comment: i am not available for chat, have you tried this one if yes then when you are getting problem?

Comment: @MohitSuthar Yes but it's not working (app crashes)

Comment: ok i ll give you answer let me know if crash happen and where

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create google map inside fragment than go threw this code

```
public class GoogleMapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

private GoogleMap googleMap;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_demo, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    intiGoogleMap();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapMapAddress));
    if (supportMapFragment != null)
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(supportMapFragment).commit();
}

private void intiGoogleMap() {
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapMapAddress));
    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    //First check permissions if accept or reject
    if (AppUtils.checkPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, getActivity()) &&
            AppUtils.checkPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, getActivity())) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (googleMap != null)
            if (mLastLocation != null) {
               //here you can place your marker
            }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Check your permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    if (googleMap != null) {
        this.googleMap = googleMap;
        this.googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        this.googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

}

and fragment_demo.xml is

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapMapAddress"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and try to run this will be showing of google map, and make sure **all permissions** and you have created app in **google developer console**. Also make sure adding **Android Key in manifest** file.

Comment: I do add a fragment, but it was giving me UI error.

Comment: Can you please look into my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41875474/google-map-doesnt-load-into-my-app-device