# Google Map is not showing properties which i set in onMapReady

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a mapview for which I am calling mapview.getMapAsync and in onMapReady I am setting mMap = map. Then i am setting various properties like adding marker, zooming the map, animating camera to current location, setting map type, and selecting location of the current target of camera but nothing seems to work. Some snippet of my code is:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mymapview, container, false);
    return view;
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (mMap == null)
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    mMap = map;
    setUpMap();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    markerLoader(true);
    markerLoader(false);
}
private void setUpMap() {
    mUiSettings = mMap.getUiSettings();
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
    mUiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mUiSettings.setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
    mUiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    mUiSettings.setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);

}
```

mymapview.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/locationMarker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/markerText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/Black"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:text="Position &amp; Click to\n  select location"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/marker"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/marker_offline" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/button_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/map_layer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/map_layers" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/zoom_out"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/map_zoom_minus" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/loc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/map_layer"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/location" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/zoom_in"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/zoom_out"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:src="@drawable/map_zoom_plus" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/gpsButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/gps"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/manualButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"``
        android:layout_below="@+id/gpsButton"
        android:src="@drawable/manual"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/priveousButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/manualButton"
        android:src="@drawable/previous"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am not able to find where i am going wrong.

Comment: @rafsanahmad yes it getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Add `mGoogleApiClient.connect();

inside `onMapReady` blow `markerLoader(false);`

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    mMap = map;
    setUpMap();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    markerLoader(true);
    markerLoader(false);
    mGoogleApiClient.connect(); 
}
```

Comment: Added mGoogleApiClient.connect(); still not working, mGoogleApiClient.connect(); was already added on onResume().

Comment: Ok try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19806967/3938407   or this link https://gist.github.com/joshdholtz/4522551

Comment: getMap() is not available for package com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView