# horizontal recycler view in info window google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have cluster google map with markers, and now when i click marker info window is opened. But i want change info window position to down and if in one place there are many things i want display a list in horizontal recycler view , and after when i click to map it should dissapear.

I Also add that now i have slide tab and in one tab i have google maps.

So it should looks like this:

[image]

Some code:
This is activity for slide tabs:

```
public class SlideTabsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_slide_tabs);
    if(SearchObjectList.getSearchObjectList().isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nic nie zostalo wybrane, wroc do SLideTabsActivity class aby zrobic jakas operacje gdy pusta lista",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));

}
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                FirstSlideTab firstSlideTab = new FirstSlideTab();
                return  firstSlideTab;
            case 1:
                SecondSlideTab secondSlideTab = new SecondSlideTab();
                return  secondSlideTab;
            case 2:
                ThirdSlideTab thirdSlideTab = new ThirdSlideTab();
                return thirdSlideTab;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return "FIRST";
            case 1:
                return "SECOND";
            case 2:
                return "THIRD";
        }
        return  null;
    }
}
```

}
In SecondSlideTab i have google map and class that is responsible for cluster in google map. This is xml file of SecondSlideTab:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="kamilmilik.flatsearch.showresultactivity.SlideTabsActivity">

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/mapView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/mapView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/mapView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/mapView" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fram_info_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/mapView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     />
```

What I should add to get this info window? I need fragment or something else? How add it to my slide tabs and my google map view ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a `RecyclerView` and align it to parent bottom. Then add a `OnMarkerClickListener` to you google map marker. When a click is detected you can feed your `RecyclerView` adapter with the content associated with that marker.

This link heps you understand how the mapview can be implemented.
[How to use MapView in android using google map V2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16536414/how-to-use-mapview-in-android-using-google-map-v2)

The marker is created in `onMapReady(GoogleMap gm)` callback.

To understand how to create a marker please read this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker

You can toggle the recycler view visibility when you click the marker.

Comment: Okey, so i must add recyclerView as fragment to my my layout where i have google map? If yes , how can i hide this recycler view when i click to map? Is any method ?

Comment: You don't need it to be a fragment. You can hide the recycler when detecting a click in the map for example. Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22473883/2062034