# how to put taken image in specific image view

Tags: java, android, image

I have an activity that contain a grid view which contain 3 card view each has an image view I want to setonclick mistenr that put the taken iamge from camera to the selected image view.

How can I fix this? By the way I'm using the same code for the three image view the issue is in the in activityresult method and I can't change  it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".inspection.ImageActivity">


    <View
        android:id="@+id/bg_top_header9"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="193dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_bg_topheader"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gridLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />



    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnCount="1"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:rowCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.343"
        app:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@color/whiteCardColor"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_img" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@color/whiteCardColor"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_img" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@color/whiteCardColor"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_img" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </GridLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


and this is the java class

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);


        bgTopHeader9 = findViewById(R.id.bg_top_header9);
        gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
        img1 = findViewById(R.id.img1);
        img2 = findViewById(R.id.img2);
        img3 = findViewById(R.id.img3);

        img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ImageActivity.this);
                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.takepic, (dialog, which) -> {
                    try {
                        captureImage();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Delete", (dialog, which) -> {

                    if (imgFile.exists()) {
                        if (imgFile.delete())
                            Toast.makeText(ImageActivity.this, mCurrentPhotoPath + "deleted", 
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_img);
                    }

                }).setNeutralButton("Cancle ", (dialog, which) -> dialog.cancel());
                final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.diag_layout, null);
                dialog.setView(dialogLayout);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setOnShowListener(d -> {
                    if (!(img1.getDrawable() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_img))) {
                        Bitmap myBitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
                         ImageView myImage = dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
                        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap1);
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();

            }
        });
        img2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ImageActivity.this);
                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.takepic, (dialog, which) -> {
                    try {
                        captureImage();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Delete", (dialog, which) -> {

                    if (imgFile.exists()) {
                        if (imgFile.delete())
                            Toast.makeText(ImageActivity.this, mCurrentPhotoPath + "deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_img);
                    }

                }).setNeutralButton("Cancle ", (dialog, which) -> dialog.cancel());
                final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.diag_layout, null);
                dialog.setView(dialogLayout);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setOnShowListener(d -> {
                    if (!(img2.getDrawable() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_img))) {
                                  
                        Bitmap myBitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
                        
                        ImageView myImage = dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
                        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap1);
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();

            }
        });
        img3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ImageActivity.this);
                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.takepic, (dialog, which) -> {
                    try {
                        captureImage();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Delete", (dialog, which) -> {

                    if (imgFile.exists()) {
                        if (imgFile.delete())
                            Toast.makeText(ImageActivity.this, mCurrentPhotoPath + " deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        img3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_img);
                    }

                }).setNeutralButton(R.string.cancle_string, (dialog, which) -> dialog.cancel());
                final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.diag_layout, null);
                dialog.setView(dialogLayout);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setOnShowListener(d -> {
                    if (!(img3.getDrawable() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_img))) {

                        Bitmap myBitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
                        ImageView myImage = dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
                        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap1);
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();

            }
        });
    }

    private void Showimage() {
        img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
                try {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ImageActivity.this);
                    builder.setPositiveButton("cancel ", (dialog, which) -> {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }).setNegativeButton("Delete ", (dialog, which) -> {

                        img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_img);
                        option = false;
                    });
                    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                    @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.diag_layout, null);
                    dialog.setView(dialogLayout);
                    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    dialog.setOnShowListener(d -> {
                        if (imgFile.exists()) {

                            Bitmap myBitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
                            
                            ImageView myImage = dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
                            myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap1);
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();
                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private void captureImage() throws IOException {

        option = true;
        String[] perms = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, perms)) {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            photoFile = createImageFile();
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ImageActivity.this, "com.xdev.pfe.utils.fileprovider", photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST);
        } else {
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, "We need permissions because this and that", 123, perms);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused") Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ImageActivity.this);
            builder.setPositiveButton("save ", (dialog, which) -> {
                File imgFile = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
                if (imgFile.exists()) {
                    byte[] imageData = null;
                    try {
                        final int THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 1024;
                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imgFile);
                        Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
                        imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, false);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                        imageData = baos.toByteArray();

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length);
                    img1.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                    System.out.println(paths);
                }
            }).setNegativeButton(R.string.recapture_string, (dialog, which) -> {
                try {
                    captureImage();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).setNeutralButton(R.string.cancle_string, (dialog, which) -> dialog.cancel());
            Toast.makeText(this, mCurrentPhotoPath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.diag_layout, null);
            dialog.setView(dialogLayout);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setOnShowListener(d -> {
                imgFile = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
                if (imgFile.exists()) {
                    Bitmap myBitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    ImageView myImage = dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
                    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap1);
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ImageActivity.this, "Request cancelled or something went wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = ImageActivity.this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",   /* suffix */
                storageDir      /*directory*/
        );

        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode, @NonNull List<String> perms) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionsDenied(int requestCode, @NonNull List<String> perms) {
        if (EasyPermissions.somePermissionPermanentlyDenied(this, perms)) {
            new AppSettingsDialog.Builder(this).build().show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what was  the issue mention clearly

Comment: how to impplement multiple image button to take picture from camera each time and image view will be replaced with the taken image from  camera

Comment: send a flag to the camera intent on each item click, send the different flag to identify which imageView call the camera and set Your image on that imageview

Comment: would you help me with that if u can :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send different `requestCode` for different `imageView` click, And `onActivityResult` check the request code set image data to your imageView

```
   capturedImageButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent photoCaptureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(photoCaptureIntent, 100);
            }
        });

  capturedImageButton1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent photoCaptureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(photoCaptureIntent, 101);
            }
        });


  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            switch (this.resultCode){
                 case 100:
                    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
                    capturedImageButton.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    break;

                case 101:
                    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
                    capturedImageButton1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    break;

               default:
                  break;
            }

        }
    }
```